# The meaning of "In general" in mathematics

Tags: terminology

What is the meaning of "in general" in mathematical texts? Does it mean usually or it means always or sometimes usually and sometimes always according to the text?

Comment: In general means for all other cases.. Context of course matters...

Comment: Depends on the text, naturally. Usually it means that there might be exceptions, but they are not representative (that is, they have probability/measure zero, they "almost never happen").

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik so: in general, in general means for all other cases

Comment: Is there a specific example of the word popping up that you had in mind?

Comment: In general, it means in general, except, of course, when it doesn't.

Comment: I think the OP might be confused by the following usage: One sometimes writes "In general, continuous functions are **not** differentiable". In conjunction with the **not**, such a statement has the be read as "the general assertion that continuity implies differentiability is false". It does **not** mean that a continuous function is **never** differentiable.

Comment: Regarding: "In general, continuous functions are not differentiable." I would declare this assertion to be false. What is meant is instead: "Continuous functions are not in general differentiable."